# an event receiver has canceled the request (item.File.CheckIn)

Tags: 2007, check-in

Sharpoint 2007, Following is a part of my powershell script which works in all web sites but MySite.

```
$item.TakeOverCheckOut();
....
$item.SystemUpdate([System.Boolean]::false);
....
$item.file.CheckIn("Checked In By Administrator");
....
```

it works everywhere but when it comes to MySite it generates following error when it treis to check in the documents. an event receiver has canceled the request 
If I log on as Administrator I can check out and check in same documents. I suspect that it can be a permission problem but the question is if I take over the ownership so it shouldn't be a permission problem.